# 'Could no load image...' error when not referencing image?

Tags: ios, xcode, nslog

The nslog gives the error "Could not load the "XXX.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "XXX". However, Image.png is never referenced in IB nor in my code. Why do I still get this error (I have also cleaned the product and build folder, no luck).

Comment: Sometimes there are things in a nib that don't show in IB.  Try right-clicking the file and opening it as source.  Search the text for the name it's complaining about.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out for future reference... It's the strangest thing -  I wasn't referencing the image anywhere in my app, but I made a new image and named it 'XXX.png' (what the log claimed I was referencing) and added it to my project. Then I deleted it from the project, and now I don't get this error anymore. So odd...

Comment: Yeah, Xcode has some weird caching bugs where xib files won't get updated on the simulator or device, even after a clean.  Next time just delete the app and install fresh.